# Passing strings to AsyncTask.execute in android?

Tags: android

Im trying to make a weather app in android where i get input from user and then tell them the current weather. main activity looks like this

```
package com.example.dellinspiron.speechrecognition;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView cityField, detailsField, currentTemperatureField, humidity_field, pressure_field, weatherIcon, updatedField;

    Typeface weatherFont;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        assert b != null;
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText c=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.city);
                EditText d=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.country);
                final String city=c.getText().toString();
                final String country=d.getText().toString();


                weatherFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf");

                cityField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city_field);
                updatedField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updated_field);
                detailsField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.details_field);
                currentTemperatureField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_temperature_field);
                humidity_field = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.humidity_field);
                pressure_field = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pressure_field);
                weatherIcon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);
                weatherIcon.setTypeface(weatherFont);


                Function.placeIdTask asyncTask =new Function.placeIdTask(new Function.AsyncResponse() {
                    public void processFinish(String weather_city, String weather_description, String weather_temperature, String weather_humidity, String weather_pressure, String weather_updatedOn, String weather_iconText, String sun_rise) {

                        cityField.setText(weather_city);
                        updatedField.setText(weather_updatedOn);
                        detailsField.setText(weather_description);
                        currentTemperatureField.setText(weather_temperature);
                        humidity_field.setText("Humidity: "+weather_humidity);
                        pressure_field.setText("Pressure: "+weather_pressure);
                        weatherIcon.setText(Html.fromHtml(weather_iconText));

                    }
                });
                asyncTask.execute(city, country); // having problems here
            }
        });



    }
```

when i try to explicitly pass the city name and country eg asyncTask.execute("rawalpindi", "Pakistan") it works, but then if i try to pass a string obtained from the text box it doesnt. 
 i have tried to get output of the string and it gives the correct output but it just isnt being passed to the execute function properly. please help.

Comment: android studio != android

Comment: Try to trim() the string when you obtain it from EditText as extra spaces  may cause the error in the result.

Comment: the trim() method worked like a charm. thank you so much.

Comment: @Adnan migrate your comment to the answer, you've deserved it.

Comment: accept the answer correct @ploofah if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `trim` the string using `trim()` method when you obtain the text from EditText as extra spaces may cause the error in the result.